# SAP Commerce (Hybris) and Apache Kafka integration consumer not getting created

Tags: java, apache-kafka, sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

I am trying to create Apache Kafka consumer / listener on SAP Commerce application.
I have followed basic steps which are given in the link:

[Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_apache_kafka.htm)

But unable to create the listener. The below error occurs on the server startup. Please advise.

```
    ERROR [localhost-startStop-7] [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing global application context!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to determine source type <S> and target type <T> for your Converter [de.hybris.platform.converters.impl.AbstractPopulatingConverter]; does the class parameterize those types?
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:93) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.addFormatters(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:1057) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:972) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.refreshContext(HybrisContextFactory.java:88) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$ApplicationContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:256) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getApplicationInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:78) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.createCoreApplicationContext(AbstractTenant.java:763) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:804) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:735) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because there is OOTB hybris converter

```
de.hybris.platform.converters.impl.AbstractPopulatingConverter
```

This is causing the IllegalArgumentException. But this OOTB converter is not required.
So, to avoid this error you can follow the steps given in the documentation as below.

[Documentation Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/EnableKafka.html)

1. Implement KafkaListenerConfigurer with your class for example,

   ```java
   @Configuration
           @EnableKafka
           public class AppConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {}
   ```
2. This will let you implement the method:

   ```java
   public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {}
   ```
3. Set the custom myMessageHandlerMethodFactory

   ```java
   registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(myMessageHandlerMethodFactory);
   ```
4. Create and add below in your config class

   ```java
    @Bean
               public MessageHandlerMethodFactory myMessageHandlerMethodFactory() {
                       DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
                       // factory configuration
                       return factory;
               }
   ```